# Show and hide contents while navigating through a menu in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I am new to Angular. I am implementing a web project using mean stack and Angular 6. There I have to open a panel and there is a menu. I want to open different html views in different components when click menu items.

For example, I have a panel which contains the menu in the left side.This is in 'dash' component. In that menu there is a menu item called 'Maps'. When I click on menu item 'Maps' it should display the view of the html in 'maps.component.html' file. Here 'dash' and the 'maps' are two different components.

What I have tried.

1. Defined a booloan variable called 'isMap' in dash.component.ts file. Set its value as false at the begining.
2. Changed the variable's value to 'true' when item's title equals to 'Maps'

eg:

```
//Select the relavant view according to the selected menu item
  onContecxtItemSelection(title) {
    if (title == "Maps") {
      this.isMaps=true;
    }
  }
```

3. Wrapped the html in maps.component.html using a div and set the 'isMap' variable using an '*ngIf'.

   eg:

```
 <div style="float: right; " *ngIf="isMaps">
        <p>Map page</p>
 </div>
```

My first question is,

1. When I click on the menu item it does not show the content of maps.component.html 
   Second question is,
2. 'isMaps' variable in maps.component.html shows following error.

**'[Angular] Identifier 'isMaps' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member'.**
I tried importing the 'maps component' to 'dash.component.ts' file as well. But did not work. So I removed that part.

Comment: The `isMaps` variable is defined in `dash.component`, so it's only available in `dash.component`, not in `maps.component`. Would routing work for your application? If not, you can define `isMaps` within a shared service

Comment: Thanks. Routing does not work for my application.

Comment: @user184994 should I implement shared service as a different component?

Comment: Not as a component, no; it should be a service. Take a look at https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#introduction-to-services-and-dependency-injection for an intro to services

Comment: @user184994 sorry for the question again. Can you please give me an example regarding my scenario. My dash component and maps components are sibilings. Not parent and child.

Comment: If you create a very basic example in StackBlitz with your 2 components, I'll create a fork that demonstrates what I mean

Comment: @user184994 Thanks. Here I have created a project 'https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzkpvz'. 'Menu' is in dash component and when we navigate through 'maps' menu item it should display that page. Please if you can help.

Comment: The dash component won't build at the moment (possibly because of missing dependencies)

Comment: @user184994 I updated the project

Comment: If you did, it doesn't look like you saved it. I'm more than happy to help out, but can you provide a StackBlitz that at least builds, and possibly even displays the dash component